# Laurent series for $\frac{1}{z^2(z^2+1)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

So what I did was $\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{z^2+1} = \frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{z^2}} = \frac{1}{z^4}\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{2n}} = \sum z^{-2n-4}(-1)^n$ and I need to know if this is correct.

Comment: Where is the series supposed to be centered at?

Comment: It didn't say in the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for the Laurentseries centered at 0,your computations are correct.

fred